# CSV seed not working for Rails database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I am trying to seed a Rails database with the content of a CSV file. I am new to RoR so I can't find my mistake. The script works well but it does not take the content of my CSV file (everything is  filled by nil).

The migration:

```
#db/migrate/x_create_transactions.rb
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions
    add_column :transactions, :siren, :integer
    add_column :transactions, :nom_ent, :string
    add_column :transactions, :adresse, :string
    add_column :transactions, :complement_adresse, :string
    add_column :transactions, :cp_ville, :string
    add_column :transactions, :pays, :string
    add_column :transactions, :region, :string
    add_column :transactions, :departement, :integer
    add_column :transactions, :activite, :string
    add_column :transactions, :date, :integer
    add_column :transactions, :nb_salaries, :string
    add_column :transactions, :nom, :string
    add_column :transactions, :prenom, :string
    add_column :transactions, :civilite, :string
    add_column :transactions, :adr_mail, :string
    add_column :transactions, :libele_acti, :string
    add_column :transactions, :categorie, :string
    add_column :transactions, :tel, :integer
  end
end
```

My rake:

```
#db/migrate/seeds.rb
require 'smarter_csv'
  options = {}
  SmarterCSV.process('lib/seeds/siren_db.csv', options) do |chunk|
    chunk.each do |row|
      Transaction.create!( {
        :siren => row[0],
        :nom_ent => row[1],
        :adresse => row[2],
        :complement_adresse => row[3],
        :cp_ville => row[4],
        :pays => row[5],
        :region => row[6],
        :departement => row[7],
        :activite => row[8],
        :date => row[9],
        :nb_salaries => row[10],
        :nom => row[11],
        :prenom => row[12],
        :civilite => row[13],
        :adr_mail => row[14],
        :libele_acti => row[15],
        :categorie => row[16],
        :tel => row[17]
      })
    end
  end
```

My model:

```
#models/transcations.rb
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
end
```

The beginning of the csv file:

```
siren;nom_ent;adresse;complement_adresse;cp_ville;pays;region;departement;activite;date;nb_salaries;nom;prenom;civilite;adr_mail;libele_acti;categorie;tel
38713707;SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75;6 RUE DE CHARONNE;;75011 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
38713707;SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75;6 RUE DE CHARONNE;;75011 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
38724340;SYND COPR DU 18 BD ARAGO 75013 PARIS;18 BOULEVARD ARAGO;;75013 PARIS;FRANCE;Île-de-France;75;Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments;2008;1 ou 2 salariés;;;;;Syndicat de copropriété ;PME;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you provide what you executed and what the error message is?

Comment: rake db:migrate (to create the db), rake db:seed (which fill the db with the csv but instead just fill it with nill for each row). I don't get any error message after the rake db:seed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## With SmarterCSV

```
options = {col_sep: ';'}
SmarterCSV.process('lib/seeds/siren_db.csv', options).each do |chunk|
  chunk.each do |row|
    p row
  end
end
```

It outputs :

```
{:siren=>38713707, :adresse=>"6 RUE DE CHARONNE", :cp_ville=>"75011 PARIS", :pays=>"FRANCE", :region=>"le-de-France", :departement=>75, :activite=>"Activits combines de soutien li aux btiments", :date=>2008, :nb_salaries=>"1 ou 2 salaris", :libele_acti=>"Syndicat de coproprit", :categorie=>"PME"}
{:siren=>38713707, :adresse=>"6 RUE DE CHARONNE", :cp_ville=>"75011 PARIS", :pays=>"FRANCE", :region=>"le-de-France", :departement=>75, :activite=>"Activits combines de soutien li aux btiments", :date=>2008, :nb_salaries=>"1 ou 2 salaris", :libele_acti=>"Syndicat de coproprit", :categorie=>"PME"}
{:siren=>38724340, :adresse=>"18 BOULEVARD ARAGO", :cp_ville=>"75013 PARIS", :pays=>"FRANCE", :region=>"le-de-France", :departement=>75, :activite=>"Activits combines de soutien li aux btiments", :date=>2008, :nb_salaries=>"1 ou 2 salaris", :libele_acti=>"Syndicat de coproprit", :categorie=>"PME"}
```

`row` is a Hash, you'll have to rename the CSV header ("NOM"->"NOM_ENT") to fit your table columns, or get the correct key for each column.

If the names fit exactly, you'll be able to use :

```
Transaction.create!(row)
```

## With Ruby CSV

I couldn't get SmarterCSV to parse the accented characters. The standard Ruby [CSV](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) works just fine :

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach('siren.csv', col_sep: ';', headers: true) do |row|
  p row.to_h
end
```

It outputs :

```
{"siren"=>"38713707", "nom_ent"=>"SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75", "adresse"=>"6 RUE DE CHARONNE", "complement_adresse"=>nil, "cp_ville"=>"75011 PARIS", "pays"=>"FRANCE", "region"=>"Île-de-France", "departement"=>"75", "activite"=>"Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments", "date"=>"2008", "nb_salaries"=>"1 ou 2 salariés", "nom"=>nil, "prenom"=>nil, "civilite"=>nil, "adr_mail"=>nil, "libele_acti"=>"Syndicat de copropriété ", "categorie"=>"PME", "tel"=>nil}
{"siren"=>"38713707", "nom_ent"=>"SYND COPR DU 6 AU 8 RUE DE CHARONNE 75", "adresse"=>"6 RUE DE CHARONNE", "complement_adresse"=>nil, "cp_ville"=>"75011 PARIS", "pays"=>"FRANCE", "region"=>"Île-de-France", "departement"=>"75", "activite"=>"Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments", "date"=>"2008", "nb_salaries"=>"1 ou 2 salariés", "nom"=>nil, "prenom"=>nil, "civilite"=>nil, "adr_mail"=>nil, "libele_acti"=>"Syndicat de copropriété ", "categorie"=>"PME", "tel"=>nil}
{"siren"=>"38724340", "nom_ent"=>"SYND COPR DU 18 BD ARAGO 75013 PARIS", "adresse"=>"18 BOULEVARD ARAGO", "complement_adresse"=>nil, "cp_ville"=>"75013 PARIS", "pays"=>"FRANCE", "region"=>"Île-de-France", "departement"=>"75", "activite"=>"Activités combinées de soutien lié aux bâtiments", "date"=>"2008", "nb_salaries"=>"1 ou 2 salariés", "nom"=>nil, "prenom"=>nil, "civilite"=>nil, "adr_mail"=>nil, "libele_acti"=>"Syndicat de copropriété ", "categorie"=>"PME", "tel"=>nil}
```

This should work out of the box :

```
Transaction.create!(row.to_h)
```

Comment: I just tried but the result is the same. I get that in console for example: Transaction.find(1)
  Transaction Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "transactions".* FROM "transactions" WHERE "transactions"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<Transaction id: 1, siren: nil, nom_ent: nil, adresse: nil, complement_adresse: nil, pays: nil, region: nil, departement: nil, activite: nil, date: nil, nb_salaries: nil, nom: nil, prenom: nil, civilite: nil, adr_mail: nil, libele_acti: nil, categorie: nil, tel: nil>
irb(main):002:0>

Comment: `nom` -> `nom_ent`

Comment: Thanks it works! One last problem, all my special characters desapear (é, ô...) even if I have put the option ":file_encoding => "utf-8"". Any clue?

Comment: Non. Ca fonctionne bien avec Ruby CSV par contre.

Answer (score 1):

Is you CSV file correctly parsed? I it separates columns via semicolon. You probably have to put that into options:

```
options = {col_sep: ";")
```